# If you can hydroponically grow White Sage starting from rock wool

Tags: hydroponic

It sounds like White Sage is hard to grow, with a 10-20% germination rate. I saw [How to grow White Sage hydroponically](https://www.gardenguides.com/109417-grow-white-sage-hydroponically.html), but it doesn't do the first step like you would hydroponically. Instead it sounds like they planted the seeds in dirt and once they germinated and grew some leaves they transplanted them to a hydroponic system.

I am new to gardening and hydroponics in general, but I am interested to know if it's possible to use a rock wool sort of system to germinate the White Sage seed, without any soil. Then perhaps it will grow some leaves just in the rock wool, and I can then transplant it to some perlite, etc.

Wondering if this is possible, and if so, how much better or worse it will likely work out as opposed to starting to germinate in the soil.

Comment: @Locasa Mawati You are talking about rockwool seed germination cubes?